# MVC5 parse double quoted JSON in the View

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, double-quotes, viewbag

I have a problem in my web app, I am retrieving data from my database and then passing it through the ViewBag to the View and finally converting the data to a javascript object.

This is an example with dummy data

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var boxer = new
    {
        Name = "Juan Manuel Márquez",
        Division = "Welterweight"
    };

    ViewBag.Data = new
    {
        Boxer = boxer
    };

    return View();
}
```

View

```
<div>
    Hello there!
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var myModel = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Data))');
            console.log(myModel);
        });
    </script>
}
```

The result is as expected: an object with the model properties. But the problem is when the name of the boxer include his alias, for example:

```
var boxer = new
{
    Name = "Juan Manuel \"Dinamita\" Márquez",
    Division = "Welterweight"
};
```

This cause the next error because the JSON.Encode generates a JSON string without escape the quotes

> VM38:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token D in JSON at position 31
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at HTMLDocument. (Index:53)
>       at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3174)
>       at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.2.js:447)
>       at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.10.2.js:118)

Any suggestion?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

You dont need Json parse here try

```
  @section scripts {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var myModel =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Data));
                console.log(myModel);
            });
        </script> }
```

and also remove the single quotes from @html.Raw
it should be looking like

```
 var myModel =@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Data));
```